# Why doesn't HttpPostedFile perform as advertised and buffer downloads to disk rather than memory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload, httppostedfilebase

I am uploading large files to an ASP.NET server using a standard HTML `<input>` control posting multipart-form data. This is an ASP.NET MVC application.

According to MSDN, the `HttpPostedFile` class buffers to disk out of the box:

> "Files are uploaded in MIME
>   multipart/form-data format. By
>   default, all requests, including form
>   fields and uploaded files, larger than
>   256 KB are buffered to disk, rather
>   than held in server memory."

I assume this means that when I access `HttpPostedFileBase` in my controller, that when I access the `HttpPostedFileBase`'s `InputStream` property, I can write the file buffer somewhere without having to worry about the server running out of memory, which is obviously an unworkable solution.

Here's a bit of pseudocode for how I'm handling each of the incoming files from `HttpPostedFileBase`.

```
for(var i = 0; i< Request.Files.Count;i++)
{
    var fileBase = Request.Files[i];
    if (fileBase.ContentLength == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // One thread per file
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
    {
        // Read from fileBase.InputStream
    }, 
    null);
}
```

My web.config's httpRuntime block looks like this:

```
<httpRuntime
  executionTimeout="1200"
  requestLengthDiskThreshold="2097151"
  maxRequestLength="2097151"
  useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
  minFreeThreads="8"
  minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
  appRequestQueueLimit="100" />
```

My implementation works, multiple files are uploaded as expected, except that the same amount of memory required to buffer the entire payload is consumed by the server. I have to assume that the InputStream is buffering everything. When I upload more files than I have memory, it predictably crashes with an `OutOfMemoryException`. Here's an image of the memory spike when uploading an 800mb file.

[image]

I know I could use a Flash/Silverlight widget or write a custom `HttpModule` to intercept uploads and handle them myself, but the current requirement would work flawlessly if `HttpPostedFile` did what MSDN says it does (or I'm doing it wrong).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why do you set

```
requestLengthDiskThreshold="2097151"
```

in the configuration? Doesn't that force the server to keep all uploads in RAM rather than buffering to disk?

Comment: Of course. I was debugging another aspect of uploading and set that without thinking. Setting it to 256kb keeps server memory where it belongs. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielCrenna by setting it to 256kb can you upload successfully?please reply.